# Find list of schema.tables from abinitio graphs

Tags: ab-initio

can you please help me to get the answer of below question: I have more than 50 ab initio graphs, in which Db2 tables have been used to fetch data, but the schema.table names are all parameterised. How to find the list of all tables with schema name. Please help with any links if available.

Answer (score 0):

Use m_db or Input table and using DBC you can tweak below queries to get the list.

select * from sysibm.systables
select name  from sysibm.systables where owner = 'Schemaname' and name like '%PROCESS_EXTRACT%'and type = 'T'

Comment: Thanks Karthick, from DB I can find all tables and its schema details, But how to find which all tables have been used in the Ab-initio graphs. 
Took all tables from DB, grep through the .mp files, that way i am getting only the tables. but I want schemaname.tablename from the graph.

Comment: Get the list of tables using grep and use it in in statement ,something like select owner , name from sysibm.systables  where name in (table1,table2,..) and type = 'T'.